# Copy-pasting records from one layer to another?

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, qgis-2.6

I am copying some records in a attribute table from layer1 and pasting those as new objects in layer2.

The first time I copied some records/objects from the attribute table of layer1, I pasted them as a new vector layer (it is layer2)
When I copy/paste a new record/object in layer2, it is visible as a new record in the attribute table of layer2, but it is not visible on the map/canvas (although the first copied objects are visible).

See the following screenshots (attribute table with 6 features/polygons and canvas with only 5 polygons)

[image: 6 attributes/polygons, one without area surface]
[image: Canvas with no more then 5 polygons]

Comment: Hello, are you working with shapefiles? those seem to be a little fragile while editing. if you have successfully pasted some features, save the shapefile again or even save it as a new shapefile. also, are all features you are dealing with in the same projection?

Comment: Yes, I am working with shapefiles. They are in the same projection Belgian Lambert 72 EPSG: 31370

Comment: I just saved it as a new shapefile. The object is in the attribute table but doesn't show up on the map/canvas...

Comment: Can you support your question with screenshots or even the new shapefile? What kind of shapefile do you have? Point, Line, Polygon?

Comment: The shape file is a polygon

Answer (score 1):

To copy features from one shapefile to another you select features from shapefile a and use copy. next step is to activate edit mode in your aimed shapefile b. you can open the attribut table [image]

next it should look like this [image]

to check everything went fine, add an area row and calculate the area to make sure there is a geometry added[image]

Comment: Thank you Dirk. I just copied to shapefile B and added the column Area. Something is wrong with the geometry. Some have a area, others do not. Strange, because in shapefile A, all the records have areas...

Comment: Going to sleep now ;-)

Comment: +1 for suggesting `$area` to double-check the outcome... btw isn't it better to set its Type as Real (decimal number), perhaps?